# change value from array list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value to the next number on each click...once it reaches the end it repeats from beginning...

http://jsfiddle.net/5nwt0u36/

html:

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="info"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var arr = [10001, 10302, 12303, 11004, 10044];

$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    $.each(arr, function(key, val) {
        $('#info').text(arr[key]);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the index into a `var`, `i` in this instance, and increment the value on each click. Also make sure to check if `i` is equal to the length of the array, if so reset it.

[A JS Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/dbknz01u/1/)

```
var arr = [10001, 10302, 12303, 11004, 10044],
    i = 0;

$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {   
    if(i === arr.length){
        i = 0;   
    }

    $('#info').text(arr[i]);
    i++;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you store an index and increment it on each click, should work

```
var arr = [10001, 10302, 12303, 11004, 10044];
var i = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    i++;
    $('#info').text(arr[i%arr.length]);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, get the current index of the current number, check the length, if at the end, repeat:

```
var arr = [10001, 10302, 12303, 11004, 10044];
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    var current = parseInt($("#info").text(), 10),
        currentIndex = arr.indexOf(current);

    var value;
    if (currentIndex == (arr.length - 1)) {
        value = arr[0];
    } else {
        value = arr[++currentIndex];
    }

    $("#info").text(value);
});
```